# Serving an angular directory and subsequently using restful API's to load data when needed with nodesj

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rest

I am writing my app and I want to do the following:

On the first request, I serve all the client side code (views, models, controllers, CSS ...) and subsequently I want to do RESTful API calls to the server to populate my app with data.

I've been looking everywhere but can't find a complete example. Connect serves a static directory but after that I don't know how to route RESTful API requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use Expressjs on top of Connect for request routing:
http://expressjs.com/api.html

Its a very straight forward framework, with tons of tutorials online. Here is a good one for getting started: 
http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

Comment: The example gave me the info I needed